# allow mixed content coding Error

Tags: javascript, html, security, https

I am sending a request from HTTPs url to HTTP. Doing this i am getting error regarding "allow mixed content".

I can fix it using browser settings by clicking on Shield icon on url bar and to allow it.

Is there any way to fix this using HTML or Javascript so that user need not to change in Browser setting and it will work without letting user know about this.

Comment: `I am sending a request from HTTPs url to HTTP`  - that's your problem. If you're using HTTPS you are best using HTTPS for your third party calls, otherwise you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1):

- For your domain you can use the HSTS Header:

> Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"

Warning: it will prevent any http requests for clients.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity

- For any domain you can use upgrade-insecure-requests:

> Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests

https://scotthelme.co.uk/migrating-from-http-to-https-ease-the-pain-with-csp-and-hsts/

http://caniuse.com/#feat=upgradeinsecurerequests

Of course, **both methods require that resources are available with https.**

Using http ressources in an https webpage is a security issue, to it's normal that browser block it. They can't just remove the lock icon and accept it: if it's a script loaded with http, it may have stolen data.